# How can I make my ui-router go to a different state from my controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following states set up:

```
    var questions = {
        name: 'questions',
        url: '/questions',
        views: {
            'menu': {
                templateUrl: function (stateParams) {
                    return '/Content/app/questions/partials/menu.html'
                },
                controller: 'QuestionsMenuController'

            },
        }
    }
    var questionsContent = {
        name: 'questions.content',
        parent: 'questions',
        url: '/:content',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: function (stateParams) {
                    var isNumber = !isNaN(parseFloat(stateParams.content));
                    return isNumber ? '/Content/app/questions/partials/detail.html' :
                                      '/Content/app/questions/partials/content.html'
                },
                controller: 'QuestionsContentController'
            },

        }
    }
```

and:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state(questions)
        .state(questionsContent);
```

When I go my menu with /questions then the controller gets a list of questions and populates the $scope.questionHeaders object.

```
var url = '/api/Question/GetQuestionHeaders?id=0';
        $http.get(url)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.questionHeaders = data;
                $scope.currentQuestion = $scope.questionHeaders[0].questionId;
                $state.transitionTo('questions.content', { content: $scope.currentQuestion })
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Error: No data returned from " + url);
            });
```

Following this I want to transition to the first in the list so I coded:

```
$state.transitionTo('questions.content', { content: $scope.currentQuestion })
```

However when I trace this it just stays in an infinte loop and it does not go to the new /questions/5 (when 5 is the questionHeaders[0].questionId).

Can someone give me some advice as to how I can make it transition to /questions/5 ?  I am happy if it goes to the new browser href but do I need to code that directly (how) or can ui-router do this for me?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can inject the $state service, and call it's transitionTo (go) method.

```
.controller('SomeController', ['$state', function($state){
    $state.transitionTo('my.state', {arg:'arg'});
}]);
```

@Cody's question:

You can also inject the $stateParams into your controller and go to a state with args:

```
.controller('SomeController', ['$state', '$stateParams', function($state, $stateParams){
        $state.go('my.state', {listId: $stateParams.listId, itemId: $stateParams.itemId});
    }]);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did in the code above but nothing happens. When I debug on that line it's hit again and again and again in a loop.

Comment: Can you make a plunkr out if so I can test it? Maybe the path to your templates is wrong?

Comment: Also, is your QuestionsContentController in the same/reachable module and does it exist?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe better to use $location

Comment: NO! That is the worst way to solve it. The whole reason for creating ui-router is to avoid using location. Try this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0274471008ab674bd685

Comment: Baba is there just the one file in that gist ?  I think for this I want to get the browser location to change. Does this happen if I use $state.transitionTo ?

Comment: @Marilou, yes, $state.transitionTo will also change your url automatically. ui-router is built in such a way that you will enter a state if you hit a particular url and your url will change if you go to a particular state. Basically url and state are always consistent.

Comment: HEY! Is there any way to `go` / `transitionTo` with queryParams? Something like `$state.go('app.lists.list.item', { listId: N, itemId: N1 }, '?edit=true')` ... ?

Comment: @Cody why not. It should work, as long as you inject $stateParams. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @baba, You're exactly right -- there's not necessary deviation to the above approach -- this works great for what I need.